# Different Behaviors of Dimensions of a Graphics Object and Pic

Tags: graphics, dimensions, tkz-graph

I am trying to create a plot with tikz (using [PlotNeuralNet](https://github.com/HarisIqbal88/PlotNeuralNet)), and I would like to make an included image of the same dimension for the height of the cube (a representation of convolutional layers) I am creating, but it seems that the `height` of the two objects works differently. Indeed, by using the same dimension `10pt` for both elements, I have a different behaviour. I've also tried with cm and px.

If follows the case:

```
{\includegraphics[width=8cm,height=10pt]{Image.png}};

\pic[shift={(0,0,0)}] at (0,0,0) {Box={name=conv1,%
        xlabel={{"64","dummy"}},fill=\ConvColor,%
        height=10pt,width=2,depth=40,zlabel=W}};
```

Would you happen to have an idea on how to make sure that both the elements have the same height?
As you see the two objects have the same specification for the dimension of the height (10pt).